# Is there a Joomla function to generate the 'alias' field?

Tags: joomla, components, alias

I'm writing my own component for Joomla 1.5. I'm trying to figure out how to generate an "alias" (friendly URL slug) for the content I add. In other words, if the title is "The article title", Joomla would use `the-article-title` by default (you can edit it if you like).

Is there a built-in Joomla function that will do this for me?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Line 123 of `libraries/joomla/database/table/content.php` implements `JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe()`. Pass in the string you want to make "alias friendly" and it will return what you need.

Comment: It's called `JApplication::stringURLSafe()` in Joomla 2.5.

Comment: In Joomla 3.* You should use ./joomla/filter/output.php
`JFilterOutput:stringURLSafe($string)`

Comment: Care @marcanuy you are missing a colon in the static method call `JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($string)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to generate an alias for your created component it is very simple. Suppose you have `click on save` or `apply button` in your created component or suppose you want to make alias through your tile, then use this function:

```
$ailias=JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($_POST['title']);
```

Now you can insert it into database.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for how to make an alias in Joomla 4, here is the solution:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Filter\OutputFilter;
```

(insert at the top of the document)

And then in the code.

```
$alias = OutputFilter::stringUrlSafe($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple PHP.

Here is the function from Joomla 1.5 source:

Notice, I have commented the two lines out. You can call the function like

$new_alias = stringURLSafe($your_title);

```
function stringURLSafe($string)
    {
        //remove any '-' from the string they will be used as concatonater
        $str = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);
        $str = str_replace('_', ' ', $string);

        //$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
        //$str = $lang->transliterate($str);

        // remove any duplicate whitespace, and ensure all characters are alphanumeric
        $str = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'), array('-',''), $str);

        // lowercase and trim
        $str = trim(strtolower($str));
        return $str;
    }
```